# Domain A to B routing

Tags: cross-domain, web-hosting

I have a domain named `AAAAAAAA.example` and I built my site there. The domain name is long. I wanted to have a second site `B.example` where I would like  `B.example/XYZ`  -> to point -> `AAAAAAAA.example/?param=XYZ` so that I offer less typing for my customers.

What is the easiest and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: It depends.  What type of hosting do you have (shared, VPS, cloud, dedicate, managed)?    What web server are you using (Apache with .htaccess, IIS, nginx, etc)?  What companies are you using for web hosting and DNS hosting?

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly

> `B.example/XYZ` -> to point -> `AAAAAAAA.example/?param=XYZ`

redirect then it's necessary to use HTTP redirect, so you'll have to host something at the address pointed by the `B.com` DNS A record that will respond with 30x HTTP redirect response. Because it needs to re-map the HTTP path (`/XYZ` to `/?param=XYZ`).

If `B.example/XYZ` -> `AAAAAAAA.example/XYZ` would be enough then you can duplicate DNS records of B and AAAAAAAA domains to point to the same address and you're done. Also, make sure that the app will accept both domain names.

Another option `XYZ.B.example` -> `AAAAAAAA.example` should be possible with only DNS CNAME records if it's OK for you.